# What are realistic expectations that a novice should have

Tags: django, jquery

I am writing this to get a more realistic view of what I should be able to achieve.

I have been learning web development for just about a month now. Below are my level of proficiency on a scale of 1 to 10 (10 being not having to use google or ask a question on stackoverflow to solve all encountered issues)

**Skills**

- Django: 5
- jquery/ajax: 4.5 to 5
- Html: 5

(just simple html code, having the "bone structure" of the site laid out without any fancy formatting or design)

- using CSS: 0 (I think it's called css)

These are, from my understanding of the skills required to develop a site.

**Am I a fast learner?**

I started a month back at 0 in all categories (with limited to medium programming experience in other languages), I don't know if this counts as fast.

**GOAL:**

As a learning experience, I am trying to develop a news website where users subscribe to different news categories (ex: 'US news', 'Europe', 'Business'...) and they would get, in their news feed (a lot like facebook's news feed that automatically gets updated) feeds that are related to the categories they are subscribed to.

I haven't tackled website design yet; even though it is just for learning purposes, I would ultimately really like to have a nice design set up for the site, and deployed it on a server just so I would go through all the steps needed to actually launch a site.

I would really like to hear some feedback on feasibility/ get some insights on some of your personal professional experience on:

1- Hey is it feasible for a newbie to learn off the internet everything he needs to pull this off!!??

2- I am having a hard time putting a "deadline" to achieve this. How long will it take you to finish this? how long do you think it takes an almost complete novice to do this :)

Any other remarks/comments are welcome,

Thanks for sharing!!

-Rami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be over-rating your django skills a little there! I'd say someone is probably at 6/10, or 7, when they're relatively comfortable with the AOP parts of django - i.e. metaclasses, decorators, and so forth. That said, apologies if you are at this level!

I dare say what you'll find yourself doing is making the site so that it works - this won't take long at all - and then doing a ~huge re-write using more sophisticated code. And so on.

Another issue you may have with a dynamic site like this is database optimizations and, though not really applicable for a feeds-based site, caching. I'm currently working on doing optimizations on a large website, where the initial programmer didn't care about efficiency so long as it worked. So it became incredibly inefficient, some pages using 1000+ queries (though not bad code, at all, really) - some model methods potentially doing 50k+ queries (ouch!). Most optimizations were fairly trivial (select_related, annotate, aggregate, update, etc) - some were outside of the ORM's scope and required raw SQL and/or efficient c-based algorithms. The latter have sped some pages up from ~700queries/7seconds to 3queries in 0.4seconds - impossible to do in just django.

All in all, how long it'll take to make the website depends on your audience. If its for <100 users, then it won't take you long at all (apart from the design, I could spend years playing with css and my site would still look ugly) - if its intended for a much larger user-base, then you could be spending a lot longer on it... in my opinion!

Comment: You are 100% correct in your statement, I don't know how to write my own custom decorator, I have no idea what AOP is, I am familiar with meta classes though I did not have the opportunity to fully used them (so therefore not very comfortable using them). I just correct the score in an edit. Thank you for the insight on the project you are currently working on!! It surely helped put things in perspective :)

Comment: No problem! By the way, are you comfortable with over-riding __init__ and save methods (etc)? And using super() to call the parent class' method, with *args, **kwargs? This kind of stuff is invaluable. If you have that stuff under your belt then you should be able ot make a pretty damn good site. Next on the learning curve is probably using the _meta attribute of models and when/why/how to use __new__(), __call__() and such. Then metaclasses, which still confuse me a fair bit - though the django source code is probably the best place to learn about them.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Hey is it feasible for a newbie to
>   learn everything he needs of the
>   internet and pull this off!!??

Completely! The information is all there. Django is an extremely well documented framework. You might have to use the brain for specific actions but most of it already exists in the framework or by using plugins. The rest you already know. As for the CSS part, get a theme from some online site and adapt it to your needs. Keep backups to revert to in case you destroy something.

> 2- I am having a hard time putting a
>   "deadline" to achieve this. How long
>   will it take you to finish this? how
>   long do you think it takes an almost
>   complete novice to do this :)

Can't help you there.. No one works the same way and that will be based on your experience, knowledge, background and so on. Start doing it and adapt as you go.

Good luck!